# How can I show all changes at once?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to view all the changes at once without having to click each time each file?

I would like to have a view like a Pull Request view where you can see all the changes scrolling down.

Visual Studio 2019

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Edited question to clarify VS version.

Comment: could you provide a snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a scrollable page view of changes is only provided in the web version. In Visual Studio in the `Teams` -> `Changes` section it shows the changed files, but one has to *click-through* them to see the difference.